# How can I do a self join in ORMLite

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to get all time entries for a specific foreman based on his supervisor's supervisor.  However, I seem to be having trouble writing a self join query in ORMLite.  See my data structure and code below.

```
public class User
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    [References(typeof(User))]
    public int SupervisorId { get; set; }
}
public class TimeSheet
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    [References(typeof(User))]
    public int ForemanId { get; set; }
}

var query = db.From<TimeSheet>()
.Join<User>()
.Join<User, User>(); // not sure how to write this one.
// .Where(super => super.SupervisorId = 2)
```

I've created a [sample gist](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=1715c6da3ec580b33c90c2a0327f9e59&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) to try and better show what I've attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = db.From<TimeSheet>()
   .Join<User>()
   .Join<User, User>((p, q) => p.Id == q.SupervisorId, db.JoinAlias("u2"));
```